# mypy: What is the need for covariant in this TypeVar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, covariance, mypy

```
U = TypeVar("U", covariant=True)

class IterableAndSized(Protocol[U], Sized, Iterable[U]): ...
```

I want to make a protocol as above that uses the Sized and Iterable abstract base classes to define an acceptable type; e.g.

```
T = TypeVar("T")

def tailvalue(index_from_rear: int, x: Iterable[T] | IterableAndSized[T]) -> T
    if isinstance(x, Sized):
        for i, val in enumerate(x):
            if i == len(x) - index_from_rear:
                 return val

    return list(x)[-index_from_rear]
```

this can help optimise retrieving values near the end of a generator expression.

---

Why do I need
`TypeVar("U", covariant=True)` rather than just `TypeVar("U")` there? IIUC it means subtypes are permitted or something, I'm sure that's okay but I don't know why it's a requirement here